# Remote installation script great in XP, doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scripting, remote

I have a script to install an .msi file out to a list of remote workstations.  Works fine going out to XP machines.  I now get error code 1603 when trying to run out to Windows 7 machines.

```
psexec -u "domain\username" -p "password" @\\domain\path\ComputerList.txt  msiexec /i "\\domain\path\InstallFile.msi" /passive /qn
```

Is it a permissions error?  The user (me) is an Administrator on the Windows 7 workstations.

Comment: Any chance it would be an UAC setting blocking you? Can you try turning off UAC on windows client ? It will require a reboot : Here 2 method : http://www.blogsdna.com/1815/how-to-disable-uac-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7-beta-1-build-7000.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try using the -h switch for psexec.  From the psexec help:

```
If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process run with the account's elevated token, if available.
```

This may resolve any issues that are occuring with UAC.